# Trouble with sizing and specificity of nav class bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm messing with bootstrap 4 nav utilities. I understand that they are automatically designated as a flexbox. I want to have the nav be vertical until md is reached at which point the nav will switch to horizontal. While vertical I want the nav to occupy 20% of the available viewport and while horizontal I want it to be container-fluid. I can turn the vertical to 20% but that overrides the horizontal as well. Help appreciated, thanks. 
Here is my code :

```css
.flex-column {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-center border">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Vertical nav on large screen or small?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [`Media Queries`](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) to target them only on medium devices. Alternatively, you can use `vw` instead of `%` for viewport width.

```css
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .flex-column {
    width: 20vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-center border">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so, if it is possible to accomplish this using bootstrap classes only.  Use the following code should you want to have vertical nav on small screen device.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .w-s-20 {
    width: 20% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills d-flex flex-column flex-md-row  justify-content-center border w-s-20 ">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

I recommend you to use the latest version of bootstrap.